# C libcurl programs immediatly terminate on Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, curl, libcurl

I am trying to make a C FTP client using libcurl. I'm writing all my code on eclipse + using minGW. I have got to the stage of including the headers/libraries (I think correctly?) but am struggling to get any sort of response out of eclipse. No errors/problems appear when I compile the code but it immediately terminates, even when putting prints etc. throughout. Any libcurl example I tried has the same issue of terminating with no response immediately.

Includes - images:
[libraries include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwgyB.png)   -  [header includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgN4z.png)

Error-ish - image:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEF54.png)

My .h files are located at `C:\curl\include\curl`
My .a and .dll.a files are located at `C:\curl\lib`

Example of non-working code:

```
/***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998 - 2019, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

/* <DESC>
 * Performs an FTP upload and renames the file just after a successful
 * transfer.
 * </DESC>
 */ 

#define LOCAL_FILE      "/tmp/uploadthis.txt"
#define UPLOAD_FILE_AS  "while-uploading.txt"
#define REMOTE_URL      "ftp://example.com/"  UPLOAD_FILE_AS
#define RENAME_FILE_TO  "renamed-and-fine.txt"

/* NOTE: if you want this example to work on Windows with libcurl as a
   DLL, you MUST also provide a read callback with CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.
   Failing to do so will give you a crash since a DLL may not use the
   variable's memory when passed in to it from an app like this. */ 
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  curl_off_t nread;
  /* in real-world cases, this would probably get this data differently
     as this fread() stuff is exactly what the library already would do
     by default internally */ 
  size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);
  return retcode;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;
  curl_off_t fsize;

  struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
  static const char buf_1 [] = "RNFR " UPLOAD_FILE_AS;
  static const char buf_2 [] = "RNTO " RENAME_FILE_TO;

  /* get the file size of the local file */ 
  if(stat(LOCAL_FILE, &file_info)) {
    printf("Couldn't open '%s': %s\n", LOCAL_FILE, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

  printf("Local file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);

  /* get a FILE * of the same file */ 
  hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* build a list of commands to pass to libcurl */ 
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_1);
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_2);

    /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* specify target */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);

    /* pass in that last of FTP commands to run after the transfer */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

    /* now specify which file to upload */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    /* Set the size of the file to upload (optional).  If you give a *_LARGE
       option you MUST make sure that the type of the passed-in argument is a
       curl_off_t. If you use CURLOPT_INFILESIZE (without _LARGE) you must
       make sure that to pass in a type 'long' argument. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)fsize);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* clean up the FTP commands list */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.